# Cleanup Comments with Deleted Stackoverflow Links

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I recently encountered a comment that lead to a question or answer that had been deleted. Is it possible, without manual flagging, for the system to clean up these dead links that are only accessible to people with enough rep to see deleted questions and answers?

Link to example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1168817/2591612

Comment: What if someone *wanted* to link to a deleted question?  That happens from time to time.

Comment: Why would you do that on StackOverflow? Meta.stackoverflow is different

Comment: Well, the first example that comes to mind is when someone deletes and then reposts their question, I often add a link to the first in the duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

While this may be helpful in some cases, more often than not, it will be confusing to readers. What if the link is buried in a long, high quality comment? Do we delete the link and risk confusing future readers of the comment as to what happened to the link? At which point people will ask for the link again causing the commenter to hunt for it, not being able to find it.  However, if we keep the link there, it at least raises the point that it once existed and was deleted so removes any sense of confusion.

Comment: Delete the comment.. if its flagged as obsolete then its likely to be deleted and screw up the conversation thread anyways.

Comment: @0A0D What if it is a high quality comment, why delete the entire comment just because a link is no longer available? I understand _some_ comments may not make sense without the content provided by the link, but deleting the entire comment will confuse more users than it will help IMHO.